# How to continue execution of function with many parameters, if one of it broken?

Tags: python, with-statement

Good day!
i have a code below:

```
def initial(*args):
    for arg in args:
        with open(arg) as f:
            print 'passed'
```

it called from this code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   initial('test_staff/1.txt', 'test_staff/d2.txt', 'test_staff/1.txt')
```

My question is, if second parametr 'test_staff/d2.txt' broken(file not exist), how to continue execute a function(with third param)?

I see several methods to do it:

1. write function to pass existance
2. use try, throw, finally.

but how it perform with "with statement from pep" ?

Thank you!

**upd: function name changed from *_*_***initial****_*_**() to ***initial***()

Comment: Please do not use `__*__` names for your own methods. Those names are considered reserved for internal stuff. There are only few cases where exceptions to this make sense (`__json__()` in a class for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to check whether the file exists or doing some try / except

```
import os

def main(*args):
    for arg in args:
        if not os.path.exists(arg):
            continue

        with open(arg) as f:
            print("passed")
```

Otherwise you could just catch the exception (`IOError`)

```
def main(*args):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            with open(arg) as f:
                print("passed")
        except IOError:
            print("File doesn't exist")
```

Some people say "Try and Catch" instead of doing many checks, there are others that prefer checking instead of trying and catching! IMHO, both of them are fine!

Comment: Your first code breaks if the file exists but the user doesn't have permission to read it, or if the file exists when tested but is then deleted before the code gets around to opening it. That's why the `try:..catch:` is generally preferred, it handles the weird edge cases without you having to think about them.

Comment: Agree. It depends on the environment, though! If it is highly concurrent (like you suggest) then the first code might be a problem. The second is more secure in any case!

Comment: it is normal to use '_with_' after '_try_' ? maybe better to use only '_try_'? can you give explanation? Thx!

Comment: @HDDimon: the `try` block surrounds the operation that might fail, whatever operation that might be. In this case, the operation that might fail is opening a file using `with open(....) as f:`, so it goes inside the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(*args):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            f = open(arg)
            print 'passed'
            break
        except:
            pass
        else:
            with f:
                do_stuff_with(f)
```

Doesn't look very nice though...

Comment: Your code seems a bit messed up there. What's intended round the `open` with a trailing colon?

Comment: @Li-aungYip: By leaving the `with` block.